# Toolbar transparency is not working in viewpager

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager

I am using viewpager for Text sliding. If i set **visibility of viewPager is GONE** my layout is like IMAGE1.otherwise IMAGE2

[image: HIDING VIEWPAGER]. 
[image: VIEWPAGER VISIBLE]
Expected Output is IMAGE3

[image]

**I need a view of Layout with trasparent Toolbar + ViewPager(Text Sliding)**

Please check my xml code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/LinearLayout_mm"
    android:background="@color/black_2"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ashik.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/one_hundred_dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            style="@style/LinearLayout_mm"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTitle"
                style="@style/LinearLayout_mm"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutTitle1"
                    style="@style/LinearLayout_mw"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    // VIEWPAGER
                        android:id="@+id/reviewpager"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_prof"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/two_ten_dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:contentDescription="Photo"
                        android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:border="true"
                        app:border_color="@color/white"
                        app:border_width="@dimen/three_dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lr_user"
                        style="@style/LinearLayout_mw_ver"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/LinearLayout_ww"
                            android:text="Welcome"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue_3"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/thirteen_sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />


                        <LinearLayout
                            style="@style/LinearLayout_mw_hor"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtUser"
                                style="@style/LinearLayout_ww"
                                android:text="User"
                                android:textColor="@color/transparent_1"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
                                style="@style/LinearLayout_ww"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_3"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/thirteen_sp"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutTitle2"
                    style="@style/LinearLayout_mm"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_bankimage"
                        style="@style/LinearLayout_mw"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:src="@drawable/indian_bank" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/style_text_view_left"
                            android:src="@drawable/img_net_bank" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnNetBanking"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/style_text_view_new"
                            android:text="Net Banking" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/LinearLayout_ww"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_new"
        android:tint="@color/black_1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

    <ashik.myapplication.CustomFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/one_twenty_dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/one_twenty_dp"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_new1"
        app:borderWidth="@dimen/zero_dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/zero_dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: toolbar is still transparent you are seeing background color

Comment: Can you please post a pic about what do you actually want? The question is confusing. I see nothing wrong here. Just using proper background color might do the job, I guess.

Comment: Please help me to fix it

Comment: Post your color code

Comment: use relativeLayout as the layout in which you are using toolbar and view pager

Comment: or add viewpager in content_main.xml

Comment: <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color> @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: viewpager in content_main.xml  is not worked @Madhur

Comment: @ParamaSudha add `#a0aade` for `colorPrimary`

Comment: @ParamaSudha I guess problem in Color code section .Let me feedback

Comment: Sorry,I changed toolbar (colorPrimary )color as #a0aade.But didnt work that. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Thanks to all.I got it.Yes problem was in Color code. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @ParamaSudha Ji Most welcome .Review my answer .

Answer (score 0):

> Color-hex gives information about colors

So Basically i already mentioned that Problem for your Color Code .
You should change it .Hope this helps

Look at here .Change Both for your Problem .

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
```